# R : Filter hourly dataset to use only data that has 4 or more observation per day

Tags: r, time-series

I'm working with a dataset that countains hourly observation from 1958 to 2020. The problem is that for some days, there is not as much hourly observations then the rest. I would like to filter my dataset and only work with the data from days with more than 4 observations.

here's a quick exemple of my data

```
time          date        hourlymax
18:00:00      1993:08:21  6
08:00:00      1993:08:23  6
11:00:00      1993:08:23  6
08:00:00      1993:08:26  3.5
```

Is there anyway of filtering the data as mentionned above?

Thanks

Comment: My data is misleading... hourlymax isn't related to the number of observation, it's jut the max value recorded in all of the hourly observations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think something like this will return data where each day has at least four observations.

### base R

```r
dat4 <- dat[ ave(dat$date, dat$date, FUN = length) >= 4, ]
```

### tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
dat4 <- dat %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  filter(n() >= 4)
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(dat) # if not already a data.table
dat4 <- dat[, .SD[.N >= 4, ], by = .(date) ]
```

Comment: Looks like it's working, thanks!

Comment: Or using `subset` `subset(dat, date %in% names(which(table(date) > 4)))`